# Generate JAVA class files for XSD in springboot using JAXB plugin error

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm new to Spring development and JAVA, i would be needing your help to resolve below error.

I'm trying to generate the JAVA class files for the XSD schema using JAXB plugin as below in pom file:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb21-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
            <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
            <generatePackage>com.mud.listcontractsretriever.unmarshal.response</generatePackage>
            <strict>false</strict>
            <writeCode>true</writeCode>
            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
            <noFileHeader>true</noFileHeader>
            <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
            <schemaIncludes>
                <include>contractListRequest.xsd</include> 
                <include>contractListResponse.xsd</include> 
            </schemaIncludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

The contractListRequest.xsd and contractListResponse.xsd as mentioned above in pom file are having some common elements due to which below error occurs stating that error generating classes again as they are already available, There is a clash here for two XSD's which are having few same elements

```
at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:82)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.populate(ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.java:333)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.populate(PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.java:59)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generateClassBody(BeanGenerator.java:545)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.<init>(BeanGenerator.java:252)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:175)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:286)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_1.XJC21Mojo.generateCode(XJC21Mojo.java:66)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_1.XJC21Mojo.doExecute(XJC21Mojo.java:41)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_1.XJC21Mojo.doExecute(XJC21Mojo.java:28)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:488)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:311)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Can you please help me and let me know how can i generate java class files for more than 1 XSD schemas having some common elements in them.

Thanks

Comment: You can use binding files for this. Please see here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html and here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnazf/index.html

Comment: You should post your complete error log. You've only posted a part of it which is not quite informative.